# Appcheck token is not printing any more for Adroid (It was printing fine before)

Tags: firebase-app-check

I have Flutter mobile app that I am currently developing locally while using real android device and Firebase emulator in the backend.  I am using Appcheck and the token was printing all the time to the console.  Recently, I noticed that the Appcheck token does not print any more.  I have not make any change related to Appcheck from my side.

I am using firebase_app_check: ^0.1.1+12

How can I get Appcheck token to print again?

Comment: I am still running into this problem even though I am using firebase_app_check: ^0.2.1+8.  Can someone please suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused by a recent update in Firebase which changed the `activate` function of App Check.

Try to activate App Check this way to obtain the debug token:

```
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance
    .activate(androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug);
```

Comment: I am already doing that.

Comment: It is strange, with the newest version (which you use) it should be enough. Have you tried with different Android device or emulator?

Comment: Yes, I used another android device and in both devices, the appcheck token gets printed after restarting the app several times.  There is no pattern that I could find to figure out when the token gets printed.

Comment: And `FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate` is used with `await` in an `async` function right when your application starts?

Comment: Thats is exactly what I am doing as well.  I followed instructions by Firebase docs.